# bijective homomorphisms between non isomorphic posets, example , explanation needed

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

Could someone please give a super simple example of a "bijective homomorphism between a non isomorphic poset"?

I don't understand the sentence marked by green in the picture taken from [Awodey](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/)'s book.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a very simple example:

- let $P = \{a,b,c\}$ where $a \le b$ and $a \le c$ ($b$ and $c$ aren't comparable);
- let $Q = \{x,y,z\}$ where $x \le y \le z$.

And let $f : P \to Q$ be defined by $a \mapsto x$, $b \mapsto y$ and $c \mapsto z$. $f$ is obviously bijective, and since $x \le y$ and $x \le z$ it's a poset homomorphism. But it's not an isomorphism, because $Q$ is totally ordered while $P$ isn't.

Comment: Thank you for this simple example !

Comment: Would a categoric theoretic isomorphism preserve the total ordering?

Comment: How would a category theoretic isomorphism look on this simple example?

Comment: @jhegedus There is no category theoretic isomorphism betwwen $P$ and $Q$. But there is one (non-trivial) from $P$ to $P$, mapping $b$ to $c$ and vice versa.

Comment: Awodey gives similar (or same ) exammple somewhere else when he speaks of invariants. Read further

Comment: @jhegedus There is no category theoretical *iso*morphism; there is a functor $P \to Q$ which is basically the same as the $f$ I defined, but it's not an isomorphism of categories.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: $P$ and $Q$ live in the category of posets $\textbf{Pos}$; I don't think they're to be used as thin categories by themselves (although I think your point still holds, of course!)

Comment: @jhegedus Since there is no bijective homomorphisms from Q to P the category theoretic argument holds good.

Comment: I think it's not clear because "bijective homomorphism" for posets is not clearly defined (perhaps that's why there are quotes?).

In the book it seems to be defined as a mapping for the elements only (non-structure preserving, 1-to-1 and onto), but sometimes it is defined as a synonym for isomorphism between algebraic structures of the same type (i.e., structure-preserving; source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism#Isomorphism).